# Wordpress: show category posts

Tags: wordpress

I have 3 boxes that i have at the bottom of my home page, i want to display in each of them a wordpress post.

Each of these posts will be under a category special1, special2, special3, how do i do this?

I have tried

```
<div class="special_box">
        <?php query_posts('tag=special3');?>
    </div>
```

But this does not work

Any ideas? I tried this, but it replaced all of my other content with just the post, which is not what i want

This is outside the wordpress loop:

```
<?php
```

$special1 = query_posts('category_name=special1');
?>

This is inside:

```
<div class="special_box">
        <?php echo $special1 ;?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This new query will show the latest post from a category and can be used more than once on a page/post (with php excecution enabled) and within the standard WP loop:

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=special1&showposts=1'); ?>
<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
<?php the_title(); ?></a><br /><?php the_content(); ?><?php endwhile; ?>
```

[Function Reference/WP Query « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be using the category number (doesn't matter). But This code is easier:

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php query_posts('cat=5'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

http://snippetcentral.com/query-posts-category/